# Server to Server / Route to Route Axios request in Express

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Inside one route, I'd like to POST an internal URL with Axios - Is this possible? (Or is this simply a localhost issue?)

Inside route:

```
exports.route = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await db.query(
      `select * from something where id ='${req.params.id}';`
    );

    const returnedData = await axios.post(`/all-data`);

    console.log(returnedData);

.....
```

Where all-data is an existing route. `(app.post....)`

However running this code gives an error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:116:16) {
      errno: -111,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 80,

.....
```

Can I make a server - to -server call like this for internal routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the whole URL for `axios`.

E.g.

```
import express from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const returnedData = await axios.post(`http://localhost:${port}/all-data`).then((response) => response.data);

  res.send(returnedData);
});

app.post('/all-data', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ name: 'teresa teng' });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`HTTP server started at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Test via `curl`:

```
⚡  curl -i -X GET http://localhost:3000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 22
ETag: W/"16-ZsgB44rkFuiax9JQYtHnPMbo0dI"
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2021 03:22:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"name":"teresa teng"}%
```

Comment: Great thank you. A supplementary question - How to ensure the request is authenticated under OAuth 2 with this Axios request?